# Why does the accepted answer sometimes not show up first?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

On [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/27080/8816) the accepted answer is not first.  In this case the accepted answer has no up-votes, but I've seen this a couple times where there were up-votes too, so I don't think that's the cause.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer was posted by the person who asked the question. Not pinning the accepted answer under these circumstances is done to prevent gaming of the system.

Comment: what's meant by 'gaming of the system'?